# Error : org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not an array: in nested objects

Tags: spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, avro, spring-cloud-stream

I have this payload and set this payload to avro classes

```
{
"tradeQuantity":13,
"tradeMarket":"sssss",
"stockName":"teststock",
"tradeType":"testtype",
"price":12.2,
"amount":12.5,
"address":{
       "stret" : "aaa",
       "city"  : "bbb"
 }
```

}

classes

```
StockHistory stockHistory= new StockHistory();
    stockHistory.setStockName(model.getStockName());
    stockHistory.setTradeType(model.getTradeType());
    stockHistory.setPrice(model.getPrice());
    stockHistory.setAmount(model.getAmount());
    stockHistory.setTradeId(new Random(1000).nextInt());
    stockHistory.setTradeMarket(model.getTradeMarket());
    stockHistory.setTradeQuantity(model.getTradeQuantity());

    Address address = new Address();
    address.setCity("sss");
    address.setStreetaddress("aaaa");
    stockHistory.setAddress(address);
```

when converting to an object mapper like

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(StockHistory.class, IgnoreSchemaProperty.class);
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

Its works when only have stockHistory without address but for nested objects how we can handle its throwing an exception

```
org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not an array: {"type":"record","name":"Address","namespace":"com.spring.cloud.streams.avro","fields":[{"name":"streetaddress","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"city","type":["null","string"],"default":null}]}
```

when using Google GSON converting object to JSON its working but I am not sure is that correct approach or not

Can anyone suggest how we can handle nested avro classes/object using objectMapper while converting to json